# How to capture viewport image in tool mode?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm trying to capture images of `MeshInstance3D` via `SubViewport` and assigning them as textures to sprites as such:

[image]

```
@tool
extends Node2D

const PIXEL_PER_METER = 100.0
@export var btn := false : set=set_btn

func set_btn(new_val):
    if(new_val):
        assign_images()

func assign_images():
    var sub_viewport=$SubViewport
    var camera=$SubViewport/Camera3D
    var mesh_instances=[ $SubViewport/A, $SubViewport/B, $SubViewport/C ]
    var sprites=[ $A, $B, $C ]
    
    sub_viewport.render_target_update_mode = SubViewport.UPDATE_ALWAYS
    camera.projection = Camera3D.PROJECTION_ORTHOGONAL
    
    for i in len(mesh_instances):
        var sprite=sprites[i]
        var mesh=mesh_instances[i]
        var mesh_aabb=mesh.get_aabb()
        camera.size = max(abs(mesh_aabb.size.x), abs(mesh_aabb.size.y))
        camera.global_position = Vector3(mesh.global_position.x, mesh.global_position.y, camera.global_position.z)
        sprite.position = Vector2(mesh.position.x * PIXEL_PER_METER, mesh.position.y * -PIXEL_PER_METER)
        #await get_tree().process_frame  # this doesn't work either
        sprite.texture=ImageTexture.create_from_image(sub_viewport.get_texture().get_image())
```

How ever this doesn't work, it doesn't capture the right image, nor does it place the sprite at right position relative to it's mesh counterpart:

[image]

For the image capture part, I suspect `SubViewport` & `Camera3D` isn't being updated quickly enough hence it captures the wrong image.

As for the position part, I believe 1 m in 3D translates to [100 pixels](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/mo9xyx/comment/gu60d8m/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) in 2D, maybe due to the unit differences the size & position of image is wrong.

So how do I implement this properly?

**Note:** I'm open to an alternate approach as long as it gives the same result, and no [`MeshInstance2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_meshinstance2d.html) does not work

[Minimal reproduction project (MRP)](https://easyupload.io/o3fch1)